# Reading excel in C# gives me an unknown date format

Tags: c#, excel, date-formatting

While reading the file and showing it in a `DataGridView` the date is shown as a number

03/25/2014 00:00 is 41723

03/25/2014 01:00 is 41723,041667

What format is this and how do I find the date/month/year/hour it represents?

```
string src = "the path";
OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + src +
                                                    "Extended Properties=\"Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1\"");

OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter("select * from [RENNES4_wk13$]", con);

da.Fill(dataSet);
dataGridView1.DataSource = dataSet.Tables[0];
```

Comment: pls show some code how are you reading the file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can convert the number into a `DateTime` in the following way:

```
//  cell as number (days since 1.1.1900 00:00)
double x = double.Parse(v);
DateTime d = DateTime.Parse("01.01.1900 00:00");
d = d.AddDays(Math.Floor(x) - 2);   //  had to subtract 2 to get it right. Why?
d = d.AddMinutes((x - Math.Floor(x)) * 24 * 60);
```

The integer part of the number gives you the days since `01-Jan-1900`.
The time is given as fraction of a day.

In your example, one hour is 1/24 of a day: 0.041667

Comment: [**interesting read on Excel dates ;)**](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/items/2006/06/16.html)

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem, here's a tip...
Before opening the file using OLEDB, release your excel file from any running thread or if you have opened it using excel services.
I learned that excel output format, for fields like date(in case of custom type), differs when they are already opened in excel services and parallely read using OLEDB.
Just give it a try.

Comment: I also noticed that the program reads differently if I have the file open.